# Как при сортировке в Pandas одну из строк поместить в конец вне зависимости от её значения

Tags: python, pandas

Есть датафрейм, содержащий следующие значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне требуется отсортировать его по столбцу Кол-во, однако строка  с "Вид дефекта" = "Прочее" должна остаться в конце. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это сделать
Что дописать в

```
data.sort_values(by='Кол-во', inplace='True', ascending = False)
```

Comment: Перенесите ваш датафрейм из картинки в код , чтоб специалист вам мог быстро и качественно помочь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

можно так:

При исходных данных:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Вид дефекта":["А","Б","В","Г","Д","Е","Ж","Прочее"], "Кол-во":[11,2,333,4,15,6,777,8]})
```

```
  Вид дефекта  Кол-во
0           А      11
1           Б       2
2           В     333
3           Г       4
4           Д      15
5           Е       6
6           Ж     777
7      Прочее       8
```

Делаем:

```
res = pd.concat([df[df["Вид дефекта"]!="Прочее"].
                 sort_values(by="Кол-во"), df[df["Вид дефекта"]=="Прочее"]])
```

Теперь в res:

```
  Вид дефекта  Кол-во
1           Б       2
3           Г       4
5           Е       6
0           А      11
4           Д      15
2           В     333
6           Ж     777
7      Прочее       8
```

Answer (score 3):

У меня получилось только через создание специального сортировочного столбца с кортежем для управления порядком сортировки:

```py
df['sortby'] = df.apply(lambda x: (x['Вид дефекта'] != 'Прочие', x['Кол-во']), axis=1)
df.sort_values(by='sortby', inplace=True, ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 2):

вариация на [тему](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1413381/457260) использования сортировочного столбца (исходные данные позаимствовал [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1413400/457260)):

```
df.sort_values(by='Кол-во', 
               ascending=False, 
               inplace=True,
               key=lambda _: df.apply(lambda x: (x['Вид дефекта']!='Прочее',x['Кол-во']),1))
'''
  Вид дефекта  Кол-во
6           Ж     777
2           В     333
4           Д      15
0           А      11
5           Е       6
3           Г       4
1           Б       2
7      Прочее       8
```